# R displays unequal p values for same dataset in two separate computers?

Tags: r, statistics

Here's the code I tried.

```
color.blind <- matrix(c(442,514,38,6),nrow=2,byrow=T)
color.blind
dimnames(color.blind) <- list(c("normal","color-blind"),c("male", "female"))
color.blind

chisq.test(color.blind,correct=F)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  color.blind
X-squared = 25.5548, df = 1, p-value = 4.3e-07
```

But when the same code is run on another pc, the p value is $1.894e-07

What  would be the reason?

Comment: Voted to close because of a typo.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your test didn't use `correct=F` as you can tell by "with Yates' continuity correction' part. Your other p-value is what i got when i used correction. Though I cant say why that is the case.
My calculations with and without correction below:

```
chisq.test(color.blind)

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  color.blind
X-squared = 25.555, df = 1, p-value = 4.3e-07
```

and with

```
chisq.test(color.blind,correct=F)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  color.blind
X-squared = 27.139, df = 1, p-value = 1.894e-07
```